# 'h' format requires -32768 <= number <= 32767

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to write a dataframe into postgreSQL database table.
When i write it into heroku's postgres SQL database, everything works fine. No problems.
For heroku postgresql, I use the connection string

```
    connection_string = "postgresql+psycopg2://%s:%s@%s/%s" % (
        conn_params['user'],
        conn_params['password'],
        conn_params['host'],
        conn_params['dbname'])
```

However, when i try to write the dataframe into GCP's cloud sql table, i get the following error...

struct.error: 'h' format requires -32768 <= number <= 32767

The connection string i use for gcp cloud sql is as follows.

```
    connection_string = \
        f"postgresql+pg8000://{conn_params['user']}:{conn_params['password']}@{conn_params['host']}/{conn_params['dbname']}"
```

the command i use to write to the database is the same for both gcp and heroku

```
df_Output.to_sql(sql_tablename, con=conn, schema='public', index=False, if_exists=if_exists, method='multi')
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using the [Cloud SQL Python Connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector) to manage your connections and take care of the connection string for you. It supports the `pg8000` driver and should help resolve your troubles.

```py
from google.cloud.sql.connector import connector
import sqlalchemy

# configure Cloud SQL Python Connector properties
def getconn():
    conn = connector.connect(
        "project:region:instance",
        "pg8000",
        user="YOUR_USER",
        password="YOUR_PASSWORD",
        db="YOUR_DB"
    )
    return conn

# create connection pool to re-use connections
pool = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    "postgresql+pg8000://",
    creator=getconn,
)

# query or insert into Cloud SQL database
with pool.connect() as db_conn:
    # query database
    result = db_conn.execute("SELECT * from my_table").fetchall()

    # Do something with the results
    for row in result:
        print(row)
```

For more detailed examples refer to the [README](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector) of the repository.

Comment: Hi Jack, thank you very much for this.

Unfortunately, I got an error saying 

"oogle.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, please see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started"

I have created the service account as a .json file and stored the .json file in the same directory as my other main python files.
How do i write the python code to authenticate using the .json files?

Comment: the example given on the google website is for storage, not for cloudsql databasesfrom google.cloud import storage

    # Explicitly use service account credentials by specifying the private key
    # file.
    storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(
        'service_account.json')

    # Make an authenticated API request
    buckets = list(storage_client.list_buckets())
    print(buckets)

Comment: I am doing something like this for google drive. I want to do the same for cloud sql. how do i do so?

gauth = GoogleAuth()
scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
gauth.credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(gSheet_CredentialsFile, scope)
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

Comment: @YingJianNg you can set application default credentials one of two ways.

1. Set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS as an environment variable pointing your json key. This can be done directly under the import statements by adding:
`os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "path/to/file.json"` or in the command line by running `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="path/to/file.json"`

2. If you have gcloud sdk installed you can just run `gcloud auth application-default login` and follow the prompts.

This should resolve the credentials error you see.

Comment: -unfortunately it still doesnt work. my code is below

    os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"Google-Credentials-.json")

Comment: pool = sqlalchemy.create_engine("postgresql+pg8000://", creator=getconn)
    with pool.connect() as db_conn:
        # Show what tables remain in database
        results = db_conn.execute("""SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables
            WHERE table_schema = 'public'""").fetchall()
        for table in results:
            print(table)

Comment: i still get the error 
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientResponseError: 403, message='Forbidden', url=URL('https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/lib-tech2/instances/db-shared/connectSettings')  
An error occurred while performing refresh.Scheduling another refresh attempt immediately

Comment: {
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Login Required.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required",
        "location": "Authorization",
        "locationType": "header"
      }
    ],

Comment: "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "CREDENTIALS_MISSING",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "service": "sqladmin.googleapis.com",
          "method": "google.cloud.sql.v1beta4.SqlConnectService.GetConnectSettings"
        }
      }
    ]
  }

Comment: did you try authenticating by setting `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="path/to/file.json"` or by using the `gcloud` command? Let me know if those cause the same errors.

Comment: Hi Jack, i did not do the export command. I just did the following. 

import os
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "path_to_your_.json_credential_file"

Comment: I want to be able to authenticate by storing the service_account.json file in my directory, and using a line of python code to authenticate

Comment: Something like 

import google.oauth2.service_account.Credentials

your_data = { 
"type": os.environ.get('YOUR_ENV_VAR'),
"project_id": os.environ.get('YOUR_ENV_VAR'),
"private_key_id": os.environ.get('YOUR_ENV_VAR'),
#... and so on with all the required Google variables....
}
your_credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(your_data, scopes=your_scopes)
service = discovery.build(api_name, api_version, credentials=your_credentials)